# Using permissions for Linux chmod

Tags: python, linux, python-3.6

I am trying the following way for executing `/bin/chmod`.

```py
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

x = oct(0o755)

p = Popen(["/bin/chmod", x, "test.py"])
o,e = p.communicate()
```

When I am using the above script, I am getting the following output

```
[sujata@vm ~]$ /usr/local/bin/python3.6 test_chmod.py 
/bin/chmod: invalid mode: ‘0o755’
Try '/bin/chmod --help' for more information.
```

In the above code if I am assigning `x="0755"` and passing it to `Popen`, it works as expected. However, Python3.6 has a different way of octal representation. I am wondering if this is the right way or am I missing here something?

Comment: Am I correct, that you only want to change the access permissions of a file?

Comment: Yes. I only want to change the access permissions.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `os.chmod()`. The way to use it is: `os.chmod($PATH$, stat.S_IWOTH)` the first parameter is the path to your file. Therefore you have to `import os`. The seccond parameter is the mode. There are the following modes:

- stat.S_ISUID − Set user ID on execution.
- stat.S_ISGID − Set group ID on execution.
- stat.S_ENFMT − Record locking enforced.
- stat.S_ISVTX − Save text image after execution.
- stat.S_IREAD − Read by owner.
- stat.S_IWRITE − Write by owner.
- stat.S_IEXEC − Execute by owner.
- stat.S_IRWXU − Read, write, and execute by owner.
- stat.S_IRUSR − Read by owner.
- stat.S_IWUSR − Write by owner.
- stat.S_IXUSR − Execute by owner.
- stat.S_IRWXG − Read, write, and execute by group.
- stat.S_IRGRP − Read by group.
- stat.S_IWGRP − Write by group.
- stat.S_IXGRP − Execute by group.
- stat.S_IRWXO − Read, write, and execute by others.
- stat.S_IROTH − Read by others.
- stat.S_IWOTH − Write by others.
- stat.S_IXOTH − Execute by others.

You can look at https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_chmod.htm

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

x = '0755'
p = Popen(["/bin/chmod", x, "test.py"])
o,e = p.communicate()
```

Solution 2:

```
import os
os.chmod("test.py", 0o755)
```

Solution 3:

```
from pathlib import Path
Path("test.py").chmod(0o755)
```

Comment: Thank you. `os.chmod` was in my list and I have tried it. But I wanted to do with `/bin/chmod` which looks like I have to pass it as a string.